# how can i copy string from file to a linked list in C?

Tags: c

Hi guys i can't copy text from a file to linked list, with integers there is no problem. There is my code. Main problem is to copy year of visit and name of city to a linked list like, I'm new in programming and tbh i can't get a lot of things. Pointers seems very hard to me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define K 50
typedef struct tourists{
    int year;
    char city[K];
    char country[K];
    struct tourists *next;
}Element;
    typedef Element *List;

List from_file_to_list(char file_name[20])
{
    FILE *file1;
    int x, y;
    char city_name[K];
    List temp, head = NULL;
    
    file1 = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if(file1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot do that");
        return NULL;
    }
    
    while(fscanf(file1, "%d %s", &x, city_name) != EOF)
    {
        temp = (List)malloc(sizeof(Element));
        temp->city[K] = city_name;
        temp->year = x;
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
    }
    return head; 
}

void show_list(List head)
{
    List temp;
    
    temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", temp->city);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    
}

int main()
{
    List head = NULL;
    head = from_file_to_list("from.txt");`
    show_list(head);
}
```

Comment: strcpy(temp->city,city_name);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
temp->city[K] = city_name;
```

doesn't actually copy a string. To copy a string in C, you have to copy each one of its characters in a loop, or alternatively use a function like [`strcpy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) or [`strncpy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy).

Remember to make sure the string is not longer than the amount of space you have available at the destination.

---

PS - If you had [compiled your program with warnings turned on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings), your compiler would have [told you](https://godbolt.org/z/7Tav3q686) there's a problem on that line:

```
source>: In function 'from_file_to_list':
<source>:29:23: warning: assignment to 'char' from 'char *' makes
integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   29 |         temp->city[K] = city_name;
      |
```

Comment: @newsenpai: 1. Next time, please compile with warnings turned on. 2. If it works, please accept this answer...